# asp.net DateTime manipulation

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have various strings of type: `7/12/2012 12:02:39 AM`
and would like to convert them all to just `7/12/2012 12:00:00 AM`
Basically the date needs be the same, just the time must be set to 12:00:00 AM for all.

What is the best way to approach that? Except just looking for " " and replacing with 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, parse them to a `DateTime`. Then you can use the `Date` property(0h)  and parse it back to a `String` by using [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx):

```
var oldDate = DateTime.Parse("7/12/2012 12:02:39 AM");
var usCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var newDateStr = oldDate.Date.ToString( usCulture );
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

<sub>only just noticed that `12 AM` is midnight not highnoon</sub>

<strike>You can create new `DateTime` instance via [`constuctor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130):</strike>

```
var newDate = new DateTime(oldDate.Year, oldDate.Month, oldDate.Day, 12, 0, 0);
```

or by adding 12 hours to the date part of the DateTime(0h):

```
var newDate = oldDate.Date.AddHours(12);
```

Comment: Sorry for my consfusing answer. I must admit that i don't know if 12 AM is noon or highnoon. So i've provided both ways (one striked), pick what you need.

Comment: Almost there. From the above I get 07/12/2012 00:00:00. Is it possible to have it as 12:00:00 AM nstead?

Comment: @user1468537: Edited my answer. I've added a `ToString` with en-us culture for the am/pm.

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Parse them as `DateTime`
2. Write them back to string using `yourDateTime.Date.ToString(@"G", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us"))`

Comment: If I do that it changes the time format to 00:02:39 and cuts off the AM. How to keep it as is?

Comment: @user1468537: BTW: Note the use of the `Date` property. This removed the time part.

Answer (score 0):

use `DateTime.Parse` and specify the `CulterInfo`

```
DateTime mydat = DateTime.Parse(myString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```